# how to select an item from a combox? and how to prevent user to add text to some texboxes?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a windows store  app and I have a control panel page where the user enter his information. I added a ComboBox where the user selects between being a doctor or patient (when he selects a doctor the user fills in all the info but a patient a selected he don't have to fill all the texboxes).

My problem is: how can I  select an item from the ComboBox?? and when this item is selected, how can I fade some texboxes or do an action to prevent him from adding info to these textboxes?? Thank You

Comment: Where is your code..Before this check this.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868195.aspx]
[http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Controls-29318599 ]

Comment: Thanks for the links!! but the first one didn't work :/

Comment: but my point is not selecting an item from a combobox, my point is that after selecting this item I want it to prevent the user from editing some textboxes....there is no problems with my code to correct so far...I just need a code that can let me prevent the user from editing a textbox when an item in a ComboBox is selected

Answer (score 1):

You'll make your life easier in the long run if you use MVVM pattern instead of putting the code in code behind. This way you put all your logic in `ViewModel` class and use binding to attach it to the user interface. Below is a short sample achieving what you need.

Let's start with the view model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // this property will hold the selected value in combo box
    private UserType _userType;
    public UserType UserType
    {
        get { return _userType; }
        set
        {
            _userType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // this property will return all available values for combo box
    public IEnumerable<UserType> UserTypes
    {
        get { return Enum.GetValues(typeof (UserType)).Cast<UserType>(); }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged must be implemented to notify the UI about changed properties
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I'm using an `enum` for different combo box values:

```
public enum UserType
{
    Doctor, 
    Patient
}
```

Since I want to show or hide a control based on my `enum` value, I'll create a converter returning the right visibility value based on the `enum` value:

```
public class UserTypeVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // I can set this property to define which enum value makes the controls visible
    // all other values make them invisible
    public UserType VisibleUserType { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (!(value is UserType))
        {
            return value;
        }

        var userType = (UserType) value;

        return userType == VisibleUserType ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now I only need to put everything together in my view:

```
<Page
    x:Class="_21643537_ComboBox.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:_21643537_ComboBox"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <!-- I'm setting my ViewModel class as DataContext for the view  -->
    <!-- now I can bind to its properties  -->
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- I instantiate  -->
        <!-- I defined that Doctor makes the controls visible -->
        <local:UserTypeVisibilityConverter x:Name="VisibilityConverter" VisibleUserType="Doctor" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="100">
        <!-- I'm binding both properties to the combo box -->
        <!-- TwoWay mode is needed to write values from UI back to ViewModel -->
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding UserType, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <!-- I use the same property to set visibility -->
        <!-- converter is used to convert enum to visibility -->
        <TextBox Visibility="{Binding UserType, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

The `TextBox` is now visible when `Doctor` is selected, and hidden otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper way to ask a question here. You have to post what you having so far, in other words what you tried before asking here. You have to be specific to a point about what you are facing any problem while achieving some thing.

Look at this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Sorry for the wrong link. It is misspelled while adding a character at the end. Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868195.aspx)

In link you can see there is event `SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"`

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Add code to display or hide Controls using Visibility Property
}
```

Let me know if you face any issues

Comment: I added this event before I posted my problem here

Answer (score 0):

You can build it all dynamically based on the user choice aka the selected index

XAML:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="comb1" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
```

c#:

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comb1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0: //doc
                TextBox name = new TextBox { PlaceholderText = "name", Margin = new Thickness(10) };
                break;

            case 1: //patient 
                //create controls.
                break;
```

now you can create different interface for each user.